# How To Give Text A Fixed Position In Your Scene?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-ui

The title says it all, I'm relatively new to Unity and what I want to do is have a tutorial scene where you'll see the floating text with instructions that will appear and disappear at the edges of your screen as you walk by it. However, the UI Text and Canvas is always overlaid on the game screen at all times, meaning any text you put on it always follows you/is pasted over the camera. Is there a setting to make text have a set position in the scene, or would I just need to make Gameobjects out of some text and place them in the scene as I would, say, a tile. Note: this is a 2D game.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, you go into your canvas and change the Render Mode to World Space, then move the canvas and text to where you want it to be in the world.